# How to operate each button separately with the redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I want to make each button move when I press it, but every button works
And why is the ID of the button that the check[id] clicked on coming out undefined
instead of being stamped on the console?

### My Select file

```
function Select() {
  const [characterFlip, setCharacterFlip] = useState(false);
  const [areaFlip, setAreaFlip] = useState(false);
  const [itemValue, setItemValue] = useState(false); // item__btn의 초기 상태
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const characters = useSelector(state => {
    return state.characters;
  });
  const areas = useSelector(state => {
    return state.areas;
  });
  const check = useSelector(state => {
    return state.checkValue.isChecked;
  });

  const characterExpanded = () => {
    setCharacterFlip(characterFlip => !characterFlip);
    console.log(characterFlip);
  };


  const characterBtn = id => {
    setItemValue(itemValue => !itemValue);
    toggle(characters[id]);
    console.log(check[id]);
  };

  const toggle = id => {
    if (id.check === true) {
      dispatch(changeCheck());
    } else {
      dispatch(changeCheck());
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="select">
      <div className="select__group character">
        <div className="select__header" onClick={characterExpanded}>
          <i
            className={
              "fa fa-solid fa-angle-" + (characterFlip ? "up" : "down")
            }
          ></i>
          <span className="select__title">어떤 빵?</span>
        </div>
        <ul className={"select__list" + (characterFlip ? " show" : " hide")}>
          {characters.map(character => {
            return (
              <SelectItem
                selectedData={character}
                selectedBtn={characterBtn}
                name={character.name}
                key={character.id}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

function SelectItem(props) {
  const check = useSelector(state => {
    return state.checkValue.isChecked;
  });

  return (
    <li className="select__item">
      <button
        className={"item__btn" + (check ? " active" : "")}
        onClick={() => {
          props.selectedBtn(props.selectedData.id);
        }}
      >
        {props.name}
      </button>
    </li>
  );
}
```

- I'm not sure if it's right to add a check to the Select Item component
- I want to add active only to the button I clicked

### My store file

```
let characters = createSlice({
  name: "characters",
  initialState: characterData,
});

let checkValue = createSlice({
  name: "isChecked",
  initialState: {
    isChecked: false,
  },

  reducers: {
    changeCheck: state => {
      state.isChecked = !state.isChecked;
    },
  },
});

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    characters: characters.reducer,
    areas: areas.reducer,
    checkValue: checkValue.reducer,
  },
});

export let { changeCheck } = checkValue.actions;
```

- List item

I really want to solve it!!!!!